# How to properly loop through a Firebase Query with completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:**

I need to loop through a Firebase query call.

My loop is initiated before the Firebase call as it holds the uids needed.

```
for uid in following_uids {
}
```

What is the proper way to loop variable `uid` into the Firebase reference & query?

```
for uid in following_uids {
    let fbRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("posts")
    //query firebase call
}
```

**Replication:**

```
func getRecentPostsFromFollowers(following_uids: [String]) {
    for uid in following_uids {// first loop
        let fbRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("posts")
            
        fbRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                let values = snapshot.children.compactMap { ($0 as? DataSnapshot)?.value }
                  
                for postData in values {
                    guard let restDict = (postData  as AnyObject) as? [String: Any] else { continue }
                    //do with data
                }
            }
        })
    }//end first loop
        
    print("Completion handler - Loop Done")
}
```

**PSEUDO code:**

```
func getFollowerUIDS(completion: @escaping (_ followers: [String]) -> Void)  {
    for uid in following_uids {
        let fbRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("posts")
        //query firebase call
    }
    completion(value)
}
```

**Specs:**

Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)
iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you'd like to combine the results from all user posts and return them as a single array of posts.

When you call `observeSingleEvent` on your document reference, the second parameter is a type of [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). This is essentially just another function that the Firebase SDK will call when it has the data ready for you.

The idea is that: because it may take some time to fetch this data, we don't want to block the rest of your function/code from running while the network call is taking place.
This means you will likely see the end of the loop `"Completion handler - Loop Done"` called before your data is made available.
This means your `getRecentPostsFromFollowers` function will return before any of your closures are called with data.

In order to allow callers of your `getRecentPostsFromFollowers` function to know when the data is ready, you can add your own completion handler to provide this data back to them.
This is a closure that you will call when you know all the data is ready.

However, because there's multiple closures with data that we need to combine, we can use something like a `DispatchGroup` for this purpose.
We'll combine the posts in an `allPosts` variable and return the data when it's combined from all the requests.

> We need to lock around the access to `allPosts` as `observeSingleEvent`'s completion handler can run on any thread, and multiple threads could try to access this variable at once.

```swift
typealias PostData = [String: Any]

func getRecentPostsFromFollowers(following_uids: [String], completion: @escaping ([PostData]) -> Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let lock = NSLock()
    var allPosts = [PostData]()
    for uid in following_uids {
        let fbRef = ref.child("users").child(uid).child("posts")
            
        group.enter()
        fbRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 5).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            defer { group.leave() }

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                let values = snapshot.children.compactMap { ($0 as? DataSnapshot)?.value }
                  
                lock.lock()
                defer { lock.unlock() }
                for postData in values {
                    guard let restDict = (postData as AnyObject) as? PostData else { continue }
                    allPosts.append(restData)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(allPosts)
    }
}
```

### Side Notes

1. Swift async/await is a more modern way to handle asynchronous-based tasks like this without some of the pitfalls in this solution, it's worth looking into.
2. Performing a separate Firestore query for each user to retrieve all their data is not very efficient.
   This is because each query requires a separate network request and will cost you at least one document read per query made, regardless if there are results or not per-user.
   You should consider structuring your data within your Firestore database so you can return all the data you require in a single query.
   This may involve denormalizing some of your data to allow for more efficient queries.

Comment: Thank you so much for your knowledge, input, and helping me out with my learning experience.